# Google spreadsheet - Formula does not show negative time

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet where I write down my working time. For example there are the following records

G9 | 05:05

H9 | 06:30

Now I want to calculate if there is time left or not. First try:

```
=IF(G9>0;G9-H9;0)
```

Second try:

```
=IF(G9>0;IF(G9<H9;G9-H9;H9-G9);0)
```

Unfortunately both ends up with a time like `22:35`. Because calculation below `0` let the system think it should start by `24:00`.

How can I display the value like `-1:25` or vice-versa for positive times (`1:05` e.g.) dynamically with a formula?

I have tried to change the format of the field, but it doesn't work since it would display all times as negative ones, even when they are positive.

EDIT:

As information if someone has troubles to work with the text values. Like @words mentioned you have to convert the value. But you also need a function if you want to work with arrays:

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(I2:I32)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can convert time to a string with `text`, and prepend "-" to it when needed:

```
=if(G9>=H9, text(G9-H9, "H:mm"), "-" & text(H9-G9, "H:mm"))
```

The result is a string, but if it's needed in later computations one can still recover the original value from it with `value`.

Comment: Thanks for your formula but I had to do some corrections to make it work. `=if(G9>=H9; text(G9-H9; "H:mm"); "-" & text(H9-G9; "H:mm"))` Without semicolons I got an error while parsing. But now it's working great. Helped me a lot. Thanks again

Comment: The separator is determined by a user's locale. In some countries it's the comma, in others semicolon. Typically, users post formulas in whatever syntax works for them, since there's no telling who will read and use the post.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for the explanation.